# How do I add a new Map entry to a Map without overwriting the entire Map?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore database, I have a document with a Map called 'Videos'.

In it, I add another Map into it that includes my video data.

So it looks like this:

```
Videos (Map) :
    2022-Oct-03-14:24 (Map):
        Title: Hi
```

Now what I want to do is, add another Map to the `Videos` with a different date.
How do I do this in Flutter?

Currently, I am doing:

```
db.collection('Collection').doc('Document').update({
    'Videos': {
        '2022-Oct-03-14:55': {
             'Title': 'Ok'
         }
    }
});
```

But what this does is, it overrides the entire `Videos` map and assigns this new map I give, so the old Map with the Title `Hi` gets deleted. How do I insert new maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding a new object inside the `Videos` map, you have two options available. The first one would be to use the `.` (dot) notation, as @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his answer, which will work perfectly fine. This means that it will indeed create the `Videos` field if it doesn't exist, and it will add the `2022-Oct-03-14:55` subfield inside it if that doesn't exist, and then the Title you put in there. However, since it's an update operation, this solution will work **only** if the document already exists, otherwise, it will fail.

If you need to create the `Videos` field inside a document that doesn't already exist, then you should consider using the set() function with merge true. However, this solution doesn't work using the `.` notation. So for that, I recommend you check my answer in the following post:

- [Problem with the initial creation of a map structure within a document in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924403/problem-with-the-initial-creation-of-a-map-structure-within-a-document-in-firest/73924470)

The second solution would be to read the document/map first. It's not mandatory but it will help you check the existence of an existing object. Why, because those objects are maps, and when it comes to maps,  if you add a record that has the same key, then it replaces the old value with the new one. So I recommend you have to check that first.

So in order to perform the addition operation, you have to:

1. Read to read the document.
2. Get the `Videos` map in memory.
3. Check if a video already exists.
4. Add the new map inside the `Videos`.
5. Write the document back to Firestore.

If you'll have a map with the exact same key as a previous key, then the data will be overwritten, meaning that you'll don't see any change in the key, but only in the value if it's different.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I will have to have one more step in between then.

Comment: Yep, but if your database allows some changes, maybe you can change that map into an array. A case in which, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10) will definitely help. It's in Java but I think you'll get the idea, right?

Answer (score 3):

While [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73934199/209103) is correct if you had an array field, you only have map fields. In that case, you can use `.` notation to updates/write only the nested field:

```
db.collection('Collection').doc('Document').update({
    'Videos.2022-Oct-03-14:55.Title': 'Ok'
});
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating a field in a nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Comment: Hey, puf. As I understand from OP's question (*Now what I want to do is, add another Map to the Videos with a different date."*), he's looking to add a new map inside an existing map, not to update a value. Besides that, I think it's ok to read the document/map first, so he can check whether a map with the same date already exists, otherwise, it will be overwritten. Besides that, if the document doesn't exist, the update operation will fail.

Comment: The write operation OP wants to perform on a map is idempotent already as far as I can see in the question, and thus doesn't require reading the data. If dot notation doesn't work on Android that should be filed as a bug, as the sample in the documentation I linked shows it for java too. Stating the workaround as a hard fact ("There is no way you can add a new object to the Videos map without reading the document first") without informing devs about such a possible bug is too blunt a recommendation especially for future visitors (once the bug you may have encountered has been fixed).

Comment: Yes, it's not mandatory to read it first. I have done the correction in both places and I'll report the bug.

Comment: I just tested the code from my answer on an Android emulator in Flutter and it correctly creates the `Videos` field if that doesn't exist, adds the `2022-Oct-03-14:55` subfield inside it if that doesn't exist, and then the `Title` or other property I put in there. It's the shorted and simplest approach to add new nested fields to a map structure as OP has, and is also shown in the linked documentation.

Comment: Hey, puf. I clarified it. The `update()` function works fine, however, the [`set()` function with merge true, doesn't[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73924403/problem-with-the-initial-creation-of-a-map-structure-within-a-document-in-firest/73924470). Here was the confusion Instead of doing what the `update()` function does, it creates a field that has the name `Videos.2022-Oct-03-14:55.Title` and the value `Ok`. It doesn't take into consideration the `.` (dot). So I updated my answer accordingly. I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Dot notation indeed doesn't work in `set` calls (I'm not sure why), but since OP already used `update` I stuck with that.